# No text on buttons

Tags: pygame

I am unable to add text over my buttons as it goes underneath, aswell as general text on the screen without it going over to the next page. Any critique helpful as im trying to learn as much as I can. And any tips on how to have a moving background like some clouds floating if you know what i mean. Full code here:

```py
import pygame, sys
import pygame_menu

mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()


from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('The Breakout')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)

background_image = pygame.image.load("BG.jpg")

def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text,2, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def text_objects(text, font):
    black = (0,0,0)
    white = (255,255,255)
    surf = pygame.Surface(font.size(text))
    surf.fill(white)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black, surf)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def main_menu():
    while True:

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

        draw_text('The Breakout', font, (255, 255, 255), screen, 215, 50)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(150, 150, 200, 40)
        button_2 = pygame.Rect(150, 250, 200, 40)
        if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                game()
        if button_2.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                options()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), button_1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), button_2)

        def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y, color):
            textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
            textrect = textobj.get_rect()
            textrect.topleft = (x, y)
            surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True


        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(60)


def game():
    running = True
    while running:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])


        draw_text('Game', font, (255, 25, 255), screen, 230, 50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(60)


def options():
    running = True
    while running:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

        draw_text('User Guide', font, (255, 25, 255), screen, 215, 50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(60)

from pygame import mixer
mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
mixer.music.play(-1)

main_menu()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add text on your buttons, you must make sure that they're drawn after your draw the button, for example:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), button_1)
drawText("hello", font, screen, button_1.x + 10, button_1.y + 10, (255, 250, 255))
```

I would also recommend that you take the drawText function out of the main menu function so you can use it elsewhere in your code.

You can add some clouds by creating a couple of white oval shapes using pygame's ellipse function. For example:

```
    size = (0, 0, 300, 80)
    cloud = pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 255, 255), size)
```

The first two parameters in the size tuple determine the x and y values and the third and fourth values represent the width and height.
You can then move this cloud by changing it's x value every iteration like so:

```
cloudX = 0

size = (cloudX, 200, 300, 80)
cloudX += 10
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 255, 255), size)
```

Just make sure the cloudX = 0 is outside of the gameloop otherwise it will keep resetting the x value of the cloud to 0

Comment: It works thanks so much!, but how would you recommend  customising the buttons instead  of having them just as squares and I meant like a moving background because i tried the pygame.movie stuff but people say they got rid of it,Thanks.

Comment: I'd say you can keep the shape of the buttons but you could add an image over them to make them look more interesting, you'd just have to make sure that the image is the same size as the button or if not you can use pygame's transform module: https://pastebin.com/TJWWfKuk

Comment: As for the moving background, I'm pretty sure you cannot play videos directly through pygame. You also can't play gifs but if you don't want to use an external library you could divide your video into a few frames, load in the frames as images *.jpgs* and then blit the images one by one to give the effect of a gif. Alternatively you could make your own background scene within pygame by creating a bunch of shapes and moving them each iteration.

Comment: Thanks again dude its looking pretty good!, now im trying to figure out how i can have the play, options and help buttons as images you can press to take it to the other screens.